# Add some numbers to existing in another cell

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Snapshot]

Our batch numbering system was M-00200116.
Here M-002 is the material code which is entered in previous column.
001 is the serial number.
16 is the year last 2 digits.

I used the concatenate formula but the serial number was coming in single digit. How to change the serial number to three digits?

Comment: Please post the necessary information to answer the question in the question itself. Links to images often break and then the question loses any potential value it had.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Stack Exchange has a contract with Imgur. If the image is uploaded through the SO toolbar (as this one was), then it will not break.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
=CONCATENATE(C3,TEXT(COUNTIF($C$2:C3,C3),"000"),16)
```

will get you enough digits in the serial number part.